# Code Completion in Eclipse CDT using FreeType2

Tags: c++, eclipse, code-completion, freetype

I'm currently programming a C++ Project which uses Freetype2 in Eclipse CDT. I like the automatic header parsing and code completion of Eclipse. However Eclipse fails to parse the standard FreeType2 include code:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
```

Eclipse doesn't understand that `FT_FREETYPE_H` is a macro pointing to a header file and therefore doesn't parse it and add its tokens to auto completion. Since Eclipse doesn't know the tokens I use in my code it signals lots of errors in the code. However the code compiles without a problem. Is there a way to get eclipse to parse those FreeType2 header files?

Simply replacing `FT_FREETYPE_H` with the include file it points to is not an option, because the same include technique is used in the FreeType2 Headers, which I don't want to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking your project, go to `Properties` -> `C/C++ General` -> `Paths and Symbols` -> `Symbols`. Then define (for your compiler type) `FT_FREETYPE_H` as your actual header file name.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. However I'm suprised this works since `FT_FREETYPE_H` is defined in `ft2build.h` which is included just fine.

Comment: Compiler and Indexer are two different entities :). You can check indexer properties under `C/C++ General` -> `Indexer`, maybe you can find some options there also.

Comment: I meant `ft2build.h` contents are parsed just fine by the indexer. Seems like it fails to then use the results of that to parse `#include FT_FREETYPE_H`.

Comment: When i add FT_FREETYPE_H to the GNU C++ symbol list, what do I specify the value as?